# How can I delete a file from /tmp, as a regular user?

Tags: linux, user-accounts

You are logged in as a regular user and working directory `/tmp/`. How, using two commands, you can delete the file `labul.txt`, which is owned by root?

This is a task that my friend was given by the professor; he claimed it is possible to do.

`sudo rm` is not an allowed answer, as we don’t have administrator permission.

Any ideas?

Comment: Assuming that this is all that the prof said (he didn't mention the possibility of pickling the sticky bit), I would say that the 2 commands are OFF and ON using the power button. Then (by default on most distribs) /tmp is emptied along with root's file while booting. I vote it up in case somebody knows a better one.

Comment: hardest to find are the easiest questions x d

Comment: do you mean two words or two commands? How about two commands 1) sudo gnome-terminal 2) rm labul.txt

Comment: 2 commands. Can i use sudo if i dont have admin permission ? or root password ?

Comment: guys problem solved we missunderstood the task xd the answer is sudo su and than rm file ..... thanks everybody